# How to Process Japanese Characters in $_GET

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, get

I do

```
http://localhost/api/test2.php?id=jr-東北本線-荒川橋梁__35.79_139.72
```

Then I do

```
$data=$_GET['id']; // Zend says that $data is jr-????-????__35.79_139.72
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding ($data); // $encoding is ASCII
$data= mb_convert_encoding($data,'utf-8'); //$data is still jr-????-????__35.79_139.72
$encoding2 = mb_detect_encoding ($data); // $encoding is still ASCII
```

The thing is I want $data to be jr-東北本線-荒川橋梁__35.79_139.72

So what should I do?

Comment: Why double posting?! Your question was answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830985/how-to-manage-id-in-database-with-japanese-characters/

Comment: And by the way - this is not Japanese characters, but Kanji which is Chinese alphabet used in Japan.

Comment: *"Zend says"* - Who is Zend? Which kind of mouth has Zend? How does it look like when Zend says something? How does that saying sound?

Comment: Hang on. I think one of them has a better answer. It as something to do with you have to encode the URL get parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the encoding of the URL data (the query part) is actually UTF-8 encoded, you don't need to do nothing at all. PHP supports UTF-8 then out-of-the-box thanks to it's binary safe strings.

So you better do not run any conversions just for having some fun trying (and failing which sucks big time).